# NSMutableArray is still null after calling the addObject method on it

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nslog

```
[_noteTitles addObject:@"title"];
[_noteDescriptions addObject:@"description"];
[self.tableView reloadData];
NSLog(@"%@", [_noteDescriptions description]);
NSLog(@"%@", [_noteTitles description]);
```

Before those lines I synthesized both "_noteDescription", "_noteTitles." When the NSLog lines are called, on the console i get "(null)" for both arrays. This function will be called multiple times (not too often) to update the contents of a table, but right now the arrays are not getting populated.

Comment: Where do you initialize the arrays? `@synthesize` does **not** init the backing instance variable.

Comment: NB `NSLog(@"%@", [foo description]);` is completely equivalent to `NSLog(@"%@", foo);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you did **not** initialize your arrays. Therefore, you are sending `addObject:` to `nil` and nothing happens. This also explains why `NSLog()` prints `(null)`.

Note that `@synthesize` generates the accessors for your property, it does **not** initialize the backing instance variable.